# Grouping Flatten List using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list

Lets say I have the following a list of flatten data:

---

Category  UserName Type Percent Grade 
         A                UserA           A1          80             A   
 
         B                UserA           A2          95             B   
 
         A                UserB          A2           70             C   
         C                UserB          A2           70            C

---

How can I group the data into this form?

UserName Category A  Category B Category C  Grade  Type 
     UserA             80                         95                        -                          A           A1   
     UserB             80                         95                        -                          A           A2

---

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You may want to use LINQ `GroupBy` (UserName)

Comment: how can UserB have a grade of A?

Comment: also how can UserB have a category B and no category C? There are other inconsistencies too.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information on what exactly you want to group on. As @Ibiza says: Your example makes little to no sense. Voted to close until more information has been provided.

Comment: That's too complex to do in a database LINQ query.. I would recommend using a stored procedure, or query all of the data, loop through all of the records, and build that dataset inline (not within the context of a LINQ query).

Comment: @BrianMains Maybe the data is in memory. This is a perfect case for a LINQ query but the question is just too poorly written to provide an answer...

Comment: @ibiza Yes it may be, which the second option (looping through the record and build the custom dataset inline) is what the main answer for inline LINQ would be, IMO.  Yes I'm sure LINQ is an option but if you look at the results, based on category A/B/C score, the grade and type is selected from the base score.  It's possible, but difficult to read from LINQ, and often if LINQ is doing it, the LINQ format for that complex processing can make maintaining it difficult.

Comment: @ibiza all the requirements are provided in the sample: select the users, flatten out the categories (hopefully the list of categories isn't dynamic, then grabs the highest grade in a particular category, and the type associated with that highest score.  Possible via LINQ yes, easier to do with a proc if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start with something like that, it's obviously incomplete since the result you want is inconsistend with the initial data

```
list.GroupBy(i => i.UserName)
   .Select(i => new {
         UserName = i.Key,
         CategoryA = i.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Grade == "A").Percent,
         CategoryB = i.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Grade == "B").Percent,
         CategoryC = i.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Grade == "C").Percent,
         // ...
      });
```